# positioning two elements inside a parent to be the same height

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have 2 divs which I need to position inside the containing `div` they need to be both the same height no matter what content goes in either of them, so they need to take the height of the tallest one hence the absolutes and top bottom set to **0**, currently the container `div` `#three` collapses and hides the two thumb divs content.

```css
section#three {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 70px 0px 70px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

section#three div.thumb-container {
    width: 40%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}

section#three div#left-thumb-container {
    left: 5%;
}

section#three div#right-thumb-container {
    right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<section id="three">
    <div class="thumb-container" id="left-thumb-container">
        content will be here to expand the divs
    </div>

    <div class="thumb-container" id="right-thumb-container">
        content will be here to expand the divs
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: i have my own content in the thumb divs i just didnt include it here..

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bu49aagh/1/)..

Comment: see answer. We don't need jquery to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend to use flexbox to solve this issue.
https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard
You can see example there.

```css
#three {
  display: flex;
}

.thumb-container {
  background: gray;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  flex: 1 0;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="three">
    <div class="thumb-container" id="left-thumb-container">
        content will be here to expand the divs
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente beatae nulla earum error reiciendis molestias praesentium, doloribus esse provident harum illum, voluptate vero ratione unde fugit repellendus laboriosam ad officiis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="thumb-container" id="right-thumb-container">
        content will be here to expand the divs
    </div>
</section>
```